# How to play a video from Content Provider

Tags: android, video, android-contentprovider, android-videoview

I might have been using the wrong search tags, but here it goes.
In the App I'm developing the user is able to upload pictures and videos.

This through recording or gallery. I'm currently trying to show a video which the user just recorded. I'm taking the Uri from Intent.getData() after an intent with MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE.

public

```
 void getCameraVideo() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(ctx.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                ctx.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, FETCHER_VIDEOCAMERA);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, Language.translate("error_phone_has_no_camera_app"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ErrorClass.log("Tried to take video, but phone has no camera.");
        }
    }
```

So I have this content Uri to my video, now how should I get about into playing this video in an VideoView? I can't seem to find any decent solution to this issue.

I simply tried this in the activity where I'm showing the video, but it just results in a black VideoView.

```
view = new VideoView(activity);
((VideoView) view).setVideoURI(uri);
((VideoView) view).start();
```

I'm sure someone solved this already, I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: add some more code...

Comment: Why not using same `uri` which you are passing with Intent when start recoding ?

Comment: I'm using the uri I get a result, I'm not passing any uri.

Comment: I see you modified the question and added the start() method after i posted my solution. It would have been nice to know you added this after i posted my answer :)

Comment: True, but that was something I forgot to add. but not the problem I asked feedback on though.

Comment: I'm not really sure why, but it works now. I added the seek and play in the onPrepared, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try as follows

```
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         //start playing here
         mp.start();
        }
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: This seems to be the solution in my case. probably because the view is not yet on stage from start in my case.

Comment: Yup, just read the VideoView docs and it specifies the following: [OnPreparedListener] Register a callback to be invoked when the media file is loaded and ready to go. That explains your previous statement where you said you saw the video for a minute earlier. The video must have been loaded faster at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a code snippet would help us figure out your problem but here goes.

Since you are implementing this in your activity, you should be able to access the VideoView from the layout. Hence I am assuming you should be able to do something like this...

```
String video_url = "some_url";
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view_id);
MediaController controls = new MediaController(YourActivityClassName.this);
videoView.setMediaController(controls);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_url));
videoView.start();
```

Hopefully, this should help you. If not, let us know and we can help you further.

P.S. Check out the android docs for more information about the videoview:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Fyi, I did state I got the content Uri from the intent, I have no such strings which link to a remote or local video file. I have no problems understanding the VideoView, just don't know how to load that video properly.

Comment: Hmm, what's the raw data in the Uri object you are retrieving from the intent? Maybe that can help narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but just a minute ago I actually saw a video. But in general is black. I am confuse. I'll let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call videoView.play() to see if your uri is correct.

Comment: There is no play() method for VideoView. Like i mentioned in the answer above, it is called start()